# Where do these spaces come from and how can I get rid of them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

beginner here. Learning Python through a book called "Breaking Ciphers with Python". As a part of a simple encryption program, I wrote this (this is only the beginning):

```
import pyperclip

fg = lambda text, color: "\33[38;5;" + str(color) + "m" + text + "\33[0m"
bg = lambda text, color: "\33[48;5;" + str(color) + "m" + text + "\33[0m"

# Simple usage: print(fg("text", 160))

msg = input('\n\nEnter your secret:\n\n')

msg_len_int = len(msg)

msg_len_str = str(len(msg))

print('\n\nChoose key (has to be less than', fg((msg_len_str), 40), '): ')

key = input('\n\nChoose your here: ')
```

As an output I get this:

[image]

I can't understand why I have 2 space chars I did not put, one before and the other after `fg((msg_len_str), 40)`.

Comment: The python `print` statement always adds spaces between arguments separated by `,`. You can eliminate the space by adding `sep=''` to the `print` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print) says:

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and written to the stream, **separated by sep** and followed by end.

To get rid of the spaces, you can set *sep* to an empty string:

```
print('\n\nChoose key (has to be less than', fg((msg_len_str), 40), '): ', sep='')
```

Comment: Or use an f-string: `print(f'\n\nChoose key (has to be less than {fg((msg_len_str), 40)}):'`

Comment: @idankor remember to mark the question as answered (and perhaps upvote the answers that were useful)!